# GCP Terraform - import ssh-keys without sudo

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Hey I just got working code that create `Compute Instance` with imported `ssh-key`. It works great, but each account terraform is creating has a `sudo` access. Is it possible to create `sudo` accounts for some key's and no sudo for the others?

```
resource "google_compute_instance" "default" {
  name         = "proxy"
  machine_type = "f1-micro"
  
  boot_disk {
    initialize_params {
      image = "centos-cloud/centos-8"
    }
  }
  // Loading keys from file
  metadata = {
    ssh-keys = file("./scripts/keys.pub")
  }

  network_interface {
    network = google_compute_network.network.id
    subnetwork = google_compute_subnetwork.subnetwork.id


    access_config {

    }
  }

  metadata_startup_script = data.template_file.squid_install_script.rendered

  tags = ["proxy"]
}
```

my snippet is posted above. Any tips?

Comment: This would normally be done by instead adding users to the instance either after creating it or baking those users and their keys in to an image that is used to create the instance. These features from providers to add a key is normally to give you an initial user that can then be used to configure the rest of the instance from there, not as a finished thing or to support multiple users out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

After creating separate ssh keys, one for sudo users and another for non-sudo users, seems that you need to edit the ssh key metadata at gcloud console:

To add or remove project-wide public SSH keys with the gcloud tool:

If your project already has project-wide public SSH keys, obtain those public SSH keys from metadata:

Obtain the existing metadata for the project:

```
gcloud compute project-info describe
```

From the output, find the ssh-keys metadata value:

Note: The ssh-keys metadata value won't appear if your instance doesn't have existing project-wide public SSH keys. Alternatively, your project-wide public SSH keys might be under a deprecated sshKeys metadata value.

```
...
metadata:
  fingerprint: QCofVTHlggs=
  items:
  - key: ssh-keys
    value: |-
      [USERNAME_1]:ssh-rsa [EXISTING_KEY_VALUE_1] [USERNAME_1]
      [USERNAME_2]:ssh-rsa [EXISTING_KEY_VALUE_2] [USERNAME_2]
...
```

where:

`[USERNAME_1]` and `[USERNAME_2]` are the usernames for your existing keys.
`[EXISTING_KEY_VALUE_1]` and `[EXISTING_KEY_VALUE_2]` are public key values that are already applied to your project. eg key 1 may content sudo and key 2 non-sudo acces.

here is the full guide that seems might be helpful for your case:

[Managing ssh keys in metadata](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/adding-removing-ssh-keys#gcloud-or-api)